# Use "go test" to list all tests case

Tags: go

With `go test -v pattern` I can select and only run the tests that matches a pattern, but is there any way that I can list all test cases without run them. There is this case that the project just handed over to me has a lot of test case and I need to select some tests to run. I know greping the sources `xxx_test.go` is a way but is there more elegant way? I mean, each test has its meta data stored in some where, right? as the tests are required to be in a specific signature(`func TestXXX(*testing.T)`). This meta data can be used to do this kind of work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just saw [this](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.9#go-test-list) in the Go1.9 release notes (draft) and I think could be what you are looking for

> The go test command accepts a new -list flag, which takes a regular
>   expression as an argument and prints to stdout the name of any tests,
>   benchmarks, or examples that match it, without running them.

Comment: For completeness, here's an example usage that lists out _every_ case: 
`go test ./...  -list=.`

Answer (score 3):

There's no saved metadata, grepping is the only way pretty much.

If you have [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), you can easily use something like this:

```
➜ ack 'func Test[^(]+'
```

Comment: doesn't help if you use `TestSuite`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use `ack` as another answer mentions, you may simply `grep -r "func Test" . | wc -l`. This works because

- grep for substring `func Test`, which should include every test func (it also includes `TestMain`)
- flag `-r` tells grep to look in subdirectories recursively
- `wc -l` will count the number of lines piped into it, which should be the number of test cases